# Do I have to use recycle Notes objects in recurrence functions?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a recursive function and it uses the Notes objects. Please tell whether I should call recycle method for these objects, or I can leave that to garbage collector?

```
function getAllUsersInDepartmentAndSub (nd: NotesDocument, arrData: Array) {
  var strSubPrefix = strTaskLibName + "getAllUsersInDepartmentAndSub/";
  try {
    var ndcResp: NotesDocumentCollection;
    var ndResp: NotesDocument;
    var ndNext: NotesDocument;
    var strTemp: string;

    if (nd) {
        ndcResp = nd.getResponses();
        if (ndcResp) {
            if (ndcResp.getCount() > 0) {
                ndResp = ndcResp.getFirstDocument();
                while (ndResp) {
                    strTemp = @LowerCase(ndResp.getItemValueString("form")); 
                    if (strTemp == "department") {
                        getAllUsersInDepartmentAndSub (ndResp, arrData);
                    } else if (strTemp == "person") {
                        strTemp = ndResp.getItemValueString("fullname");
                        if (@Member(strTemp, arrData) <= 0) {
                            arrData.push(strTemp);                          
                        }
                    }
                    ndNext = ndcResp.getNextDocument(ndResp);
                    ndResp.recycle();
                    ndResp = ndNext;
                }
            }
            ndcResp.recycle();
        }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    writeInfo(strSubPrefix, e, true, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add at least a snippet code.

Comment: recycle() doesn't do Java garbage collection, it releases the C objects. The Java garbage collector doesn't release C objects, it releases Java memory. They work together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: Recycle Recycle, Recycle!

You have to recycle all Domino objects as soon as they are not needed anymore.
And you have to be carefull: If you miss an instance it is horrible to find a recycling problem in your code.

In your code above, your NotesDocumentCollection *ndcResp* is not recycled when an error is thrown, and your server runs into allocation problems sooner or later.

You should use the *finally* statement and recycle all objects used in your function, so they will be cleaned up even if something in your method goes wrong.

Comment: I would add: Recycle! Recycle! Recycle!